# HtmlUnit: making ajax call to get json data after login success

Tags: htmlunit

I tried to login in some sites with HtmlUnit with this code:

```
    HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://somesites.com/");
    HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page1.getElementById("FormLogin"); 
    HtmlInput name = form.getInputByName("user_name"); 
    name.setValueAttribute("my_password"); 
    HtmlInput password = form.getInputByName("password"); 
    password.setValueAttribute("my_password"); 
    HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton) page1.getElementById("btnX"); 
    HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

And this sites using ajax to show its data. But this ajax call can not be accomplish if login not succeeded. In chrome browser I can do this by typing in address bar like https://somesites.com/success/site.json  so If I delete some cookies variable this never return any result.

My question was, how to make ajax call that maintain browser session after login success?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to set a AjaxHandler for your Webclient

```
webClient.setAjaxController(new AjaxController(){
            @Override
            public boolean processSynchron(HtmlPage page, WebRequest request, boolean async)
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

then, also make sure that the cookies are being stored (*note that this should only be necessary if you need to initialize a new WebClient with old Cookies*):

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
webClient.setCookieManager(cookieManager);
```

Now you have a WebClient which stores your Cookies. Do your working login, and then simply execute the ajax call via Javascript:

```
page.executeJavaScript("[ajax call]").getJavaScriptResult();
```

If you only want to access the json data, you can simply navigate to the url and get the text. **IF** you are successfully logged in, it will work:

```
HtmlPage jsonPage = webClient.getPage("https://somesites.com/success/site.json ");
System.out.println(jsonPage.asText());
```

From there on you can parse it as JSON or do whatever you need to do with it.